# Partitioning by % of the sample in PL SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, ranking, partition

I have the following data set:

```
Ranking Segment Month
1   1   201501
2   1   201501
3   1   201501
4   1   201501
5   1   201501
6   1   201501
7   1   201501
…   1   201501
567 1   201501
1   2   201501
2   2   201501
3   2   201501
4   2   201501
….. 2   201501
456 2   201501
1   1   201502
2   1   201502
3   1   201502
4   1   201502
5   1   201502
6   1   201502
7   1   201502
…   1   201502
326 1   201502
1   2   201502
2   2   201502
3   2   201502
4   2   201502
…   2   201502
562 2   201502
...........
```

I need to split every segment into groups that contain 5% of it. Since every segment has different number of sales each month, could you give me any idea how can I split each segment into 20 groups containing 5% of it order by ranking?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `count(*)` as a window function.  It is unclear what type of sample you want for each group.

The following does a first "n" sample, assuming that `ranking` has no gaps or duplicates:

```
select t.*,
       floor( 20 * (ranking - 1) / cnt) as grp
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by segment, month) as cnt
      from t
     ) t;
```

If there are gaps or duplicates, you can use `row_number()` to get a proper enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your expected output is, given your input data. Perhaps `ntile()` is what you're after, e.g.:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT LEVEL ranking, 1 SEGMENT, 201501 mnth FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 21 UNION ALL
                     SELECT LEVEL ranking, 2 SEGMENT, 201501 mnth FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 40 UNION ALL
                     SELECT LEVEL ranking, 1 SEGMENT, 201502 mnth FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 60 UNION ALL
                     SELECT LEVEL ranking, 2 SEGMENT, 201502 mnth FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 80)
SELECT ranking,
       segment,
       mnth,
       NTILE(20) OVER (PARTITION BY mnth, SEGMENT ORDER BY ranking) grp
FROM   sample_data;

   RANKING    SEGMENT       MNTH        GRP
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1     201501          1
         2          1     201501          1
         3          1     201501          2
         4          1     201501          3
        ...
        19          1     201501         18
        20          1     201501         19
        21          1     201501         20
         1          2     201501          1
         2          2     201501          1
         3          2     201501          2
         4          2     201501          2
         5          2     201501          3
        ...
        36          2     201501         18
        37          2     201501         19
        38          2     201501         19
        39          2     201501         20
        40          2     201501         20
         1          1     201502          1
         2          1     201502          1
         3          1     201502          1
         4          1     201502          2
         5          1     201502          2
         6          1     201502          2
         7          1     201502          3
        ...
        54          1     201502         18
        55          1     201502         19
        56          1     201502         19
        57          1     201502         19
        58          1     201502         20
        59          1     201502         20
        60          1     201502         20
         1          2     201502          1
         2          2     201502          1
         3          2     201502          1
         4          2     201502          1
         5          2     201502          2
         6          2     201502          2
         7          2     201502          2
         8          2     201502          2
         9          2     201502          3
        ...
        72          2     201502         18
        73          2     201502         19
        74          2     201502         19
        75          2     201502         19
        76          2     201502         19
        77          2     201502         20
        78          2     201502         20
        79          2     201502         20
        80          2     201502         20
```

N.B. ntile will fill the earlier buckets first, e.g. for segment 1 and month 201501 in my example above, grp = 1 has 2 rows, whereas all the others have 1. If you want it so that it's the later buckets that get filled up more, you can simply reverse the order of the ntile, and then subtract that from the number of buckets + 1, so in your case, that would be:

```
21 - NTILE(20) OVER (PARTITION BY mnth, SEGMENT ORDER BY ranking DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `NTILE(20)` which divides the data in chunks of 5% each.

```
select ranking, segment, month
from
(
  select
    ranking, segment, month,
    ntile(20) over (partition by segment, month order by ranking) as tile
  from mytable
)
where tile = 1
order by month, segment, ranking;
```